# Julia analog to ipython (not a notebook e.g. IJulia)?

Tags: julia

ipython provides a shell around the python REPL with line numbering, history, and magics.  The julia REPL has a lot of great features like help and shell, but there are still some features I miss like magics, history and line numbering. Can I get these in Julia?

not looking for notebooks, e.g. Jupyter

Comment: Maybe you might also wanna look at http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html . It works with IJulia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OhMyRepl.jl](https://github.com/KristofferC/OhMyREPL.jl) is a Julia REPL enhancement library.

Comment: not bad,  OhMyREPL.input_prompt!(string(VERSION) * ">", :green)  works.  would like to be able to include and increment a line number.  anyompt way to include a function in the prompt?

Comment: I'd open a Github issue for any feature request. If the package doesn't already do this, it's definitely up its ally.